# How can I get my Django server to reload when I change the HTML in dev mode without clicking the refresh button?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project. Right now (if you're the dev) you can make changes to the HTML pretty easily. i'm not having any issues with that, i just want to know how to get the server to reload when the HTML changes. here's the github.

https://github.com/jeffcrockett86/django-unchained

Answer (score 0):

You could have the client poll the server (eg. every 10 seconds). The server could then respond with a timestamp (e.g. unix millis). If the time is after the client was loaded (you could have the server put this in an `<input type=hidden>`, the client runs `window.location.reload();`